# how to print a message from c code to Tkinter

Tags: python, c, user-interface, tkinter

I write a simple c programe for print some text.so i create a GUI in Tkinter.I want to show the result of `printf("current sum= %d",sum);` of c code in pop up box when user click the button.

my c programe:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
int a,b,sum=0;
printf("File created...\n");
sum=sum+10;
printf("current sum= %d",sum);
}
```

run the command `gcc aa.c` create a executable named as `vvv`.how to make a pop up window to show the printf result in Tkinter using executable ?..I am newbie in Tk.please help me.. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use subprocess and capture the output of the executable.

```
import subprocess
output = subprocess.check_output('./vvv', shell=True)
```

Edit:

If you also wanted to know how to create a popup, have a look at this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_messagebox.htm) and give the variable `output` instead of "Hello World"

If you want to extract the last printed one only, you could use:

```
last_line = output.split('\n')[-1]
```

Here, your executable's output is cut looking for `newline`; into elements in a list and the list's last element is taken out as `last_line`.

Comment: i want to print the 2nd message only.how i select that one ?